# Webview does not display anything in JFrame pane

Tags: java, swing, javafx, webview

In my `JFrame` pane I wanna dislay a `webview`, the decare of class is :

```
public class MainTabbedForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
```

I have added a `Button` named `Display Web`and here is the code of this :

```
        private void siteSurveyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
JFXPanel myFXPanel = new JFXPanel();
myFrame.add(myFXPanel);    
  Platform.runLater(() -> {
      BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
      WebView webComponent = new WebView();

      webComponent.getEngine().load("http://google.com/");

      borderPane.setCenter(webComponent);
      Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,450,450);
      myFXPanel.setScene(scene);
});

    }
```

But when I run the program and press the `Display Web` Button it does nothing!
And nothing in `Netbeans` output displaye, No error or anything.
Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing

```
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks sir,
And I have another question, I wanna ask it, but before wanna know.
My Webview is displaying a page that is on my local host.
And it need authentication. (When I go to that page in browser, browser wants the user and password, so when I run it from java,webview displays 401 Unauthorized, Is it possible to display it?

Comment: @me_the_seven: That's new question; look for [`HttpClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20HttpClient).

Comment: @trashgod I just asked 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387512/display-webview-with-authentication-inside-program

Comment: @James_D congratz on reaching >100k

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks. You too :).